# How to include group-level predictors using lme4?

Tags: lme4-nlme, modeling, multilevel-analysis

I want to fit the following model where the response variable draws a binomial distribution.
I have two group level predictors (g1 and f1) that I want to use to model the intercept and slope

Model:
Pr (yi=1)=aj+bj∗x1

aj=γ0+γ1∗g1

bj=ƞ0+ ƞ1∗f1

Can anybody tell me how to write it using glmer?